# Install Greenplum DB 4.2.5.2 and 4.2.6.2 within same host (Single Node)

Tags: greenplum

Can I install Greenplum DB 2 versions,
version 4.2.5.2 and 4.2.6.2 within same host?

Can run simultaneously?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, It can do.

I already tested, just install different path, user owner and port.

**Ex.**

GPDB 4.2.5.2

- /usr/local/greenplum-db-4.2.5.2
- owner is "gpadm4252" user
- port base start from 40000 (segment hosts)
- master host post is 5432

GPDB 4.2.6.2

- /opt/greenplum-db-4.2.6.2
- owner is "gpadm4262" user
- port base start from 45000 (segment hosts)
- master post is 6432